# Is putting the javascript before the closing body tag okay on an asp.net website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance

I pretty much stated what I have to ask.  But is taking all of your external .js files and putting them **before** the closing body tag on your master pages okay on an asp.net website?

I'm just going off of what yslow and google speed have been showing.  I can't combine these javascripts, so I'm trying to load them "**after page load**", but doing so makes them useless; **some of my jquery things don't work**.

I moved my .js files above the opening body tag, and they work.  What am I doing wrong?  And what could I do to load my .js files **after page load**?  Thanks for any advice anybody can offer!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put them in the head? You need to put them before you need them. If you have jQuery/Javascript code in the middle of your body or in the head section, you can't just include the external files after. HTML is parsed from top to bottom, so your Javascript will be executed as soon as its read.

Comment: It really depends on what the contents of these files are. If they are a bunch of utility functions that won't be called until a later time, then by all means, put them at the end of the body. But if you have inline code in your head/body that directly calls something in your external file(s), then that file(s) needs to be put before your inline code. You can always refactor your code in some way, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: Thank you @Ian!  I think I'm starting to learn a little bit about Javascript ... thanks to your comments and other comments from others.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is putting the javascript before the closing body tag okay on an asp.net website?"

Short answer.  Yes.

Long answer.  It depends upon the javascript.

Some things might not work so well after page load because, as written, they just *need* to load certain resources in DOMReady or before, and the subsequent logic might count on that.  That is, if you have any jQuery that adds images on DOMReady, and then need to process those images, get their heights or whatever, you might have a bit of code that runs when the page is loaded (after the images are loaded).  If the page has *already been* loaded, this strategy doesn't work.  `onload` doesn't fire twice, IIRC.

Did it have to be written that way? No, it might be better to write some code that only runs after each of the images (or whatever other resources) have been verified to have been loaded, which is generally easy enough if you have the right code snippets in mind, but it's not trivial, either.

"What am I doing wrong? And what could I do to load my .js files after page load?"

There's alotta ways things can be done "wrong", and I bet one could probably write a whole chapter of all kinds of checks and still not cover all cases.  I'm not saying this to discourage you from attempting to rewrite so that they could be loaded after page load, because I think covering the *common* cases is easy enough--I just don't trust myself to accurately list the most common cases off the top of my head.

Comment: Wow, @JayC, you gave me a lot to think about ... I guess I have to do some more research and become as educated as you (and others) are at this ... you're right though ... some jquery things work perfectly on the root folder, then when you get into subfolders ( for instance, ussvision.com and then ussvision.com/services/ and then ussvision.com/services/cognex ... and even then, ussvision.com/services/cognex/more/cognex.aspx ... it gets confusing, even though I add the extra ../ to every .js file.  Hey, I really do appreciate your time in reading and responding to my question! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It is okay and usually considered best practice to put your js files right before the closing body tag, even in an asp.net website.  It can get a little annoying/tricky/chaotic with master pages though.

On the plus side, you only have to reference jquery (or whatever) once and you're set.  But then if you're using javascript/jquery in your body's controls/partials it will be executed before the files on your master page are loaded.

Here are a couple things you can do to combat these race conditions...

Wrap your javascript in a `window.onload = function() { /*your code*/ }`. This will wait till the page is done loading (images, external files, etc.) before being called.

My choice (working on asp.net MVC) is to use `RenderSection()`. [Details here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx).  There  might be an equivalent in Webforms, maybe someone can chime in there.

Comment: Good advice... except there's no good excuse to use `window.onload = function() { /*your code*/ }.` in a *reusable* javascript file, especially when using jQuery and given that jQuery provides you a common way to add multiple event handlers via `$(window).load(function () { /*your code*/ });`.

Comment: You're right. I could have been clearer. The use case I was imagining was having js code inside of the controls/partials (wrapped in script tags). In that case, jquery wouldn't even be loaded yet and `$` would be undefined.  I would hopefully never put that in an external, reusable file :)

Comment: Thank you for the information, @brains911!  I'm getting there ... still not there yet, but I just want to minimize the number of http requests when loading a page.  I appreciate your advice, and have already bookmarked your link in my fave's ... thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help. If you're looking to reduce http requests, i've used [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) and it seems to work well in combining/minimizing external files.

Answer (score 1):

As they stated in the comments, JavaScript loads from top to bottom. So if in your body you call a function that you define in your scripts that are loaded at a later date you may/will have an error.
What you probably want to do is move those scripts (the ones in the middle of the body) into it's own file and surround them with a document ready guard.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Your code in here
});
```

This will guarantee that the code is executed after the document dom is ready.
Also make sure to add this document after your libraries and dependencies.

This will also make your JavaScript easier to maintain.

Comment: I believe if jquery is also at the bottom of the page doc ready will fail cause `$` will be undefined.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's why I mentioned to add this document after the libraries not before.

Comment: sorry, i missed that. my bad.

Comment: Thank you, @theprogrammer!  I'm not entirely sure as to what you mean, but I know I'll figure it out -- it sounds like great advice to me.  I mean, say, some .js files can be moved down to just above the closing body tag, but others can't ... just depends on the javascript, which I know nothing about!  hehe .... I've been using .jscompress --- http://jscompress.com/ -- to reduce file size, but you and others are giving me enough knowledge to where I think I know what I should do.  Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question!

Comment: You are welcome. The only library I'm aware off you can't move down is modernizr and some other shims libraries that detect or add functionality into the dom. Anything else should be possible to move to the bottom of the file.
Cheers.